# .push() is not working outside of the for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have already handled a response from an API call. I then export the data into a function that i'm using a `for` loop inside. The `const diomerda` is passed to the ejs file where i am outputting the array data from the API. However the data in the array is over 5000 entries, so i want to run a for loop to populate the ejs file with the entire array. But when I use `loop.push` it does not populate the `const loop`. `console.log(loop)` just reads `[]`.

Once the `const loop = []` is populated with the array i was then going to pass the data into the `const diomerda = [json.entries[loop].character.name]`

I'f anyone has any other ideas on how to acheive what i'm trying to do then please feel free to send away. Thanks in advance.

```javascript
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => ejsoutput(json))
}

function ejsoutput(json) {
    const loop = []
    console.log(loop)
    const diomerda = [json.entries[0].character.name, json.entries[1].character.name, json.entries[2].character.name]
    for (var i = 0; i < json.entries.length; i++) {
        loop.push(i)
    }
    res.render('index', {
        leaderboard: diomerda
    })
}
});
```

Comment: Seems like you're printing `loop` with `console.log` before you put any data inside so it's naturaly gives you `[ ]`

Comment: Yep you was right. My god i feel stupid haha. Thanks a lot. Also do you know the best way for me add this array to my data?

Comment: I would suggest to simplify it to something like this: `const diomerda = json.entries.map(x=> x.character.name)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Once the `const loop = []` is populated with the array i was then
> going to pass the data into the `const diomerda = [json.entries[loop].character.name]`

If what you want is to populate `diomerda` with each character name return from the api, do this

```
function ejsoutput(json) {
    const diomerda = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < json.entries.length; i++) {
        diomerda.push(json.entries[i].character.name);
    }
    console.log(diomerda);
}
```

OR in simpler terms

```
function ejsoutput(json) {
    const diomerda = json.entries.map(item => item.character.name);
  
    console.log(diomerda);
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was after! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To debug, print (log) the json object, instead of the empty loop array (shoule get you on track).

Json should be a promise. That's probably what you're running into.
See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json

Try something like

```
json().then(function(json) {
      
});
```